# How do I compare data and schema of on-prem vs off-prem?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We're working on migrating our database (~400 tables) from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL Azure. We're currently in the proof-of-concept stage, figuring out the process we'll be following. We have a process that we think is solid but **I'd like to perform some validation diffs on both schema and data** to confirm that we have a successful migration. I've never done this before with SQL Azure and am looking for a good way to do this.

How can I perform this verification effort on both the schema and data?

Ultimately, this is a one-time migration (we'll do it a few times but the **real** migration will only be done once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx)? This has schema compare built-in, and can also identify objects and language constructs in your on-premises database that aren't compatible with Azure. It is free to download from Microsoft.

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) appears to do this decently well. I'm still nailing down the settings to ignore certain thing (like `NOT FOR REPLICATION`) but at a glance, this seems like the tool I want.

Answer (score 1):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is another option. Open Source and the price is right. It's also useful for migrating between SQL Server and other [Databases](http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html).